# "Capture GPU Frame" issues in Xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am using Xcode, V-8.3.2. I have got 2 devices:

1. iPhone 6. (iOS 10.3.2)
2. iPhone 7. (iOS 10.3.2)

I am trying to profile GPU usage for OpenGLES 3.0 based app (C++) I am working on. The first device, when I press "Capture GPU Frame" , tries to perform the capture, then after a few seconds Xcode pops up the following notifications:

> Replayer terminated unexpectedly with error code 5.Please report the
>   frame capture file then file a radar
>
> Timed out (5)

<s>When I try to debug the same app on the second device, The "Capture GPU frame" menu is disabled (non clickable). Also no "FPS" gauge is shown in the debug panel on the left in the Xcode window.</s> **This one I solved with restart of the Mac.**

The app runs fine, no crashes. Before I upgraded to the latest Xcode, the GPU frame capture worked fine for the first device. The iPhone 7 - I have no idea, because I didn't have this one before. I tried to read possible solution to the first [problem on Apple Developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/72071). Quite a few people reported that "timed out(5)" capture error, but I found no solution.
Some people suggest to downgrade to iOS prior to 10.3. I tried to reset the device to factory settings, and it doesn't reset to the iOS version older than 10.3.2, which is the newest one.

Comment: Have you found any solutions to this? I am experiencing the same issues.

Comment: Nope. It only worked for me with iPhone 7 .Bloody Apple tools...

Comment: I was seeing this connecting to an iOS 10 device (iPad retina), upgraded to iOS 11 and it went away.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue with **Xcode 10.2** and an iPhone SE (iOS 12.2) when executing compute kernels.

In my case, the issue was only related to single pass compute kernels, when tested with running video frames, the Frame Debugger works normally.

Unfortunately, I don't have a fix but I did stumble on a work around for my configuration: If I press the Home Button on the phone during the capture process, Xcode will enter the frame debugger as expected.

This only works if I press Home while Xcode displays

> "Capturing GPU Frame: 1 command buffer captured".

If I press Home while Xcode displays

> "Capturing GPU Frame: Replaying Frame",

then I still get the behaviour described in the OP.